# Woocommerce- Blank content on checkout column after inserting a hooked function with get_value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I've been trying to hook this function in one of the "Order Hooks" of the Woocommerce Checkout page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'add_box_conditional' );
function add_box_conditional ( $checkout ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'test', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('test form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('conditional test'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'test' ));
}
```

If i try to get the value of the custom box in any order hooks, the order info just hangs and stops loading. I've tried with another type of custom fields and the same happens.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sndSM.jpg)

If I hook the function outside the order contents works perfectly. The custom check box will be used to add a fee (post validation), as it is a very important option for our shop I want it inside the order details, so it can have a strong focus. Is there a way to make the function work on these hooks, or should I put it anywhere and move it with a simple but not so clean CSS overwritte?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really unclear… What is the context? what are you trying to do? what is the purpose? Where this "test" value should come from? … An action hook is just the way to insert some code to be executed on a specific location (here before order review section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just get the value like that `$checkout->get_value( 'test' ));`.
Hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` and get the value from $`_POST` there. Then add a custom fee to the order if the checkbox was checked.

Like this:

```
function add_box_conditional() {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'test', array(
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
        'class'       => array( 'test form-row-wide' ),
        'label'       => __( 'conditional test' ),
        'placeholder' => __( '' ),
    ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'add_box_conditional' );


function edit_order( $order, $data ) {

    if( ! isset( $_POST[ 'test' ]  ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $checkbox_value = filter_var( $_POST[ 'test' ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    if( $checkbox_value ){
        $fee = 20;

        $item = new \WC_Order_Item_Fee();
        $item->set_props( array(
            'name'      => __( 'Custom fee', 'textdomain' ),
            'tax_class' => 0,
            'total'     => $fee,
            'total_tax' => 0,
            'order_id'  => $order->get_id(),
        ) );
        $item->save();
        $order->add_item( $item );
        $order->calculate_totals();
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'edit_order', 10, 2 );
```